# How can I 'mention' someone with the create new chat thread for MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[Create chat thread](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_post_chatthreads)

I'm trying to create a new thread and mention the team the same way you could by typing @team and waiting for it to resolve.

I've tried both @ and  in the content but both come through as text